# ListView Adapter gets info from a LinkedHashSet<UserItem>. How to pass one of those UserItems to next activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

in my android app, when the user opens their app, I get all their items from the database, create a POJO UserItem (id, name, price and so on) for each one and then put all those UserItem objects in a LinkedHashSet that I can pass around

When they open the My Items screem, it gets the LinkedHashSet and using an enhanced for loop, creates several ArrayLists (array list for the ids, array list for the names and so on) in order to populate the ListView items with data.

But then the user clicks one of the list items and I want to start the Item Profile activity and pass the whole UserItem object to it (instead of passing the ID and doing another Database query for just this item's info (because I already have this info in the UserItem object))

How do I do that?

I cannot obtain a UserItem object from the LinkedHashSet by the userItem.getId() because LinkedHashSets do not support this feature.

Here is some code:

```
public class MyProfileItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Double> itemPrices = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> itemIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Context context;
    private LinkedHashSet<UserItem> myItems;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageWebView iMyItemsFeedItemImage;
        TextView tvMyItemsFeedItemName;
        TextView tvMyItemsFeedItemPrice;

    }


    public MyProfileItemAdapter(Context context, LinkedHashSet<UserItem> myItems) {

        this.context = context;
        this.myItems = myItems;

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        fillDataInArrays(myItems);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return itemIds.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return itemIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_adapterable_my_profile_item, parent, false);
        }
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iMyItemsFeedItemImage = (ImageWebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iMyItemsFeedItemImage);
        holder.tvMyItemsFeedItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyItemsFeedItemName);
        holder.tvMyItemsFeedItemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyItemsFeedItemPrice);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.tvMyItemsFeedItemName.setText(itemNames.get(position));
        holder.tvMyItemsFeedItemPrice.setText("$" + String.valueOf(itemPrices.get(position)));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

// Transporter is a custom class for easy passing different objects to other activities
                Transporter.instance().userItem = ???; // TODO how to get the item with this ID?

                Intent itemProfile = new Intent (context, ItemProfile.class);
                context.startActivity(itemProfile);
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    } // End of getView

    private void fillDataInArrays(LinkedHashSet<UserItem> myItems) {
        for (UserItem userItem : myItems) {
            itemIds.add(userItem.getItemId());
            itemNames.add(userItem.getItemName());
            itemBrands.add(userItem.getItemBrand());
            itemPrices.add(userItem.getItemPriceAquired());
            itemImages.add(userItem.getItemImage());
        }
    }

} // End of Class
```

The UserItem (not the whole thing, there a lot of fields)

```
public class UserItem {

    private int itemId;

    private String itemName;

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }


} // End of Class
```

The transporter class:

```
public class Transporter {

    public Transporter() {

    }

    static Transporter transporter = null;

    public static Transporter instance() {
        if (transporter == null) {
            transporter = new Transporter();
        }
        return transporter;
    }

    public LinkedHashSet<ItemImage> itemImages;
    public UserItem userItem;

} // End of Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the id of the item you want via

```
  long id = getItemId(position);
```

iterate through and look for it

```
  LinkedHashSet<UserItem> set = new LinkedHashSet<UserItem>();
  ...

    Iterator<UserItem> iter = set.iterator();
    UserItem item = null;
    while (item == null && iter.hasNext()) {
        UserItem local = iter.next();
        if (local.getId() == id) {
            item = local;
        }
    }
```

obviously instead of creating `LinkedHashSet<UserItem> set` you would use the set you have created elsewhere

Comment: I will try this. So at the end of this the UserItem item = null will turn to an actual Item that I need?

Comment: while (selectedItem = null && itererator.hasNext()) { - on this line I get the following error (The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) null, boolean)

Comment: It sounds like you need to go and do beginner Java turorials. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/ has some very good ones

Comment: come on man, help me out here I need to get through this. I have 25 books on Java that Im in the process of reading

Comment: Yes, you're correct JK, thanks. I've corrected my answer to the double equals now for anyone else looking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your user item [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

public class UserItem {

```
private int itemId;

private String itemName;

private UserItem(Parcel in) {
     itemId = in.readInt();
     itemName = in.readString();
}

...

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(itemId);
    dest.writeString(itemName);
}

public static final Creator<UserItem> CREATOR = new Creator<UserItem>() {
    @Override
    public AppStoreItem createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new UserItem(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public UserItem[] newArray(int i) {
        return new UserItem[i];
    }
};
```

} // End of Class

Comment: Im not having problem with transporting the user Item, I have a problem obtaining one particular User Item from the LinkedHashSet by its ID

Comment: You need to iterate through and compare the items to whatever you know you are looking for. Do you know how to iterate through the set?

Comment: I've added it as a new answer so I could leave you the parcelable code which you will probably also need